# Reiniciando índices para cada novo cliente

Tags: phpmyadmin, índices, chave-primária

preciso de um auxílio de vocês. Possuo um pequeno sistema que permite o cadastro de empresas, sendo que cada uma pode conter um ou mais associados. Veja um resumo das tabelas:

```
//Tabela Empresa
emp_codigo (chave primaria)
emp_nome_empresa
emp_telefone

//Tabela Associados
ass_codigo (chave primaria)
ass_empresa (chave estrangeira -> emp_codigo)
ass_nome
ass_telefone
```

Realizo o cadastro de empresas com seus devidos associados. Gostaria, no entanto, de configura-lo de forma que, para cada nova empresa cadastrada, o cadastro de seus respectivos associados iniciassem a partir do código 1, e não seguir a sequencia padrão do auto incremento da chave primaria (ass_codigo).

Neste caso, pensei em criar um outro campo (ass_codigo2) para a tabela associados, e fazer esse tratamento manualmente. Existe uma forma mais automática para isso dentro do phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, para que isso funcione você teria que criar duas colunas de índices, uma pra ser a chave primaria, e uma pra ser o código do associado. Assim o código de associado sempre poderá começar do 1, porém se for chave primaria como você está usando, não vai ter jeito.

Comment: Isso mesmo Ronivaldo, pensei em criar um segundo campo para isso. Como já existe a chave primaria (ass_codigo), iria criar "ass_codigo2", por exemplo, que seria o código "manipulável" do associado.

Comment: É o correto a se fazer.

Comment: Blz, Obrigado Ronivaldo